# "eliminated by erasure" warning in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples

I have a code that checks the four tuple input as follows:

```
if (v.isInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]) {
  val value = v.asInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]
```

I got warning `eliminated by erasure` from Scala compiler:

```
8: non-variable type argument Int in type (Int, Int, Int, Int) is unchecked since it is 
eliminated by erasure
[warn]     if (v.isInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]) {
```

What's this for, and how to change the code to remove the warning?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you checking the type at runtime?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the JVM, type parameters or "generics" are 'erased' in the class file byte code. Only the base type is retained. For example if you have

```
val v: Tuple4[Int, Int, Int, Int] = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Then this type can be identified at runtime only as

```
Tuple4[_, _, _, _]
```

In most cases this doesn't matter, as your type checking occurs during compile time, so that information is still there. But if you have a value at runtime, and you test at runtime if it is an instance of `Tuple4`, the tuple's element types are not known.

In other words, your `if` clause will be `true` for *any* `Tuple4`, no matter if the values are integers or not. Try your test with `("a", 'b', 3.4, true)`, it will "match":

```
def test1(v: Any): Option[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = 
  if (v.isInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)]) 
    Some(v.asInstanceOf[(Int, Int, Int, Int)])
  else
    None

test1((1, 2, 3, 4)).map(_._1)  // Some 1
test1(("a", 'b', 3.4, true)).map(_._1)  // runtime error!
```

---

The good thing is—if you have a *value* at runtime, then you can just test for the individual tuple elements:

```
def test2(v: Any): Option[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = v match {
  case (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int, d: Int) => Some((a, b, c, d))
  case _ => None
}

test2((1, 2, 3, 4)).map(_._1)  // Some 1
test2(("a", 'b', 3.4, true)).map(_._1)  // None
```